# Problems with the assync of Angular IO

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I have a problem with the assync of Angular IO. 
I have the code:

```
 private getPeople(serachOption: number, serachText: string): void{
  if(serachOption == 0){
    this.service.getPeopleNome(serachText)
    .subscribe((response)=> {
      this.limparCampos();
      if(response != null){
        this.People = response;
      }
    }, (erro)=> {
      console.log(erro);
    });
  }else if(serachOption == 1){
    this.service.getPeopleCpf(serachText)
    .subscribe((response)=> {
      this.limparCampos();
      if(response != null){
        this.People.push(response);
      }
    }, (erro)=> {
      console.log(erro);
    });
  }else if(serachOption == 2){
    this.service.getPeopleSus(serachText)
    .subscribe((response)=> {
      this.limparCampos();
      if(response != null){
        this.People.push(response);
      }
    }, (erro)=> {
      console.log(erro);
    });
  }

  if(this.People == undefined){
    Console.log("List Empty");
  }
 }
```

I have some calls to my services according to my search option.
But even if it brings results, the application will always display the "List Empty" message. I now that the reason is the async, but I don't now How I will fix this.

Comment: Just move that check into the relevant `subscribe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason this doesn't work is indeed the asynchronous calling of service functions.

you should probably pass an additional paramater in your getPeople function, which will be a callback function. you should then call this callback function after you got data from your service. There you can return your this.people array as a parameter of the callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this

```
if(this.People == undefined){
    Console.log("List Empty");
  }
```

if you want to log that `this.People` have values in it then you should log after this code or in `else` condition

```
if(response != null){
        this.People = response;
      }
```

**For information:** you never know that `this.People` is `undefined` or `null`, so you should just add check like this

```
if(!this.People){
    Console.log("List Empty");
  }
```